# Show size of logs in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I want to know the size of my project's logs so I can delete the biggest ones.

With [`gcloud logging logs list`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/logs/) I can list all my project's logs. However, there is no size displayed.

How can I list the size of my project's logs with `gcloud` or the Google Cloud Console?

Comment: First, you do not want or need to delete your Stackdriver logs. Enable exporting the logs to BigQuery or Cloud Storage. Then you can easily delete old records (BQ) or files (Cloud Storage).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can view the total size of your logs by looking under the "Ingested (MTD)" tab at the [Logs Ingestion](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/usage?_ga=2.237192896.-1723601513.1570176570) page of Stackdriver Logging in the Cloud Console. The logs will be sorted by size by clicking on it.

If you wish, you can exclude a specific log (exclusion query) or resource type from ingestion to minimize charges, as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions#create-filter) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions#excluding-resource) respectively. Remember, however, that you are given a [free log allotment of 50 GiB per month](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#logging-costs).

Comment: OK, thank you,
But how do these entries correlate with the ones in `gcloud logging logs list`?
For example, I can't find the log "Kubernetes Container" listed under "Log Ingestion" in the result of `gcloud logging logs list`.

Comment: @HaroldL.Brown - Stackoverflow is not a chat group. Create a new question.

Comment: @Harold L. Brown Each log from the output of `gcloud logging logs list` corresponds to a resource type. You can find a list of the resource types which are shown on the Logs Ingestion page [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/v2/resource-list#resource-types). Other than that, there is no other way to view the size of the logs.